# Queue.js: Can you access the number of items in a queue()?

Tags: javascript, queue.js

I am processing many files through a queue() using defer().  I am wondering if from within one of my defer processes I an access the number of items in the queue?  I did not see any accessors that would give me this, although the source of queue.js looks like there are attributes that may be accessible, I am just not sure how.  Ideally I would be able to get the total number of items that started in the queue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> looks like there are attributes that may be accessible

No. Those are variables that are local to the `queue()` scope, they're not accessible from outside. There are no getters either, so you need to keep track of how many items you queued yourself.

> be able to get the total number of items that started in the queue

Notice that a queue is always "started" as empty by calling `queue()`. You can add tasks to it at every time, so only you know yourself *when* "starting" is finished.